# Input Data Structure for Matlab Neural Network Toolbox

Tags: matlab, input, neural-network

My neural network has for example 2 inputs. First input has dimension 3, second input has dimension 2.

I want to simulate the network with a time series composed of 3 timesteps with the structure described above, is the following the correct (and standard) form of the data?

```
X = {[x;x;x] [x;x;x] [x;x;x]; [x;x] [x;x] [x;x]}
```

And if I want to simulate with 3 concurrent inputs is the correct form

```
X = {[x x x; x x x; x x x];[x x x; x x x]}
```

?

Comment: I'm not sure about your understanding of artificial neural networks. Typically, the number of inputs of the network should be equal to the dimensionality of the input vectors, and the dimensionality of the input vectors should be always the same, i.e., it does not change from one input vector to another.

Comment: I clearly understand your point; but it was only an example about the data structure in matlab environment; it WAS NOT a real application. By the way i can see no reason why a neural network should not accept multiple inputs with different dimensions. Anyway, in my example every input sample has the same dimension. Every input sample is composed of 2 vectors; the first has dimension 3, the second has dimension 2.

Comment: The reason is that if you leave an input empty, you are probably assuming that the input is equivalent to zero in your computations, i.e., not taking into account that input. However, zero means something, it is not equal to a null value, thus this has no much sense.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding, and my poor english doesn't help.
I agree that input samples should be identical in dimension but the structure of the single input can have different vectors with different dimensions. It is not the case of the standard MLP of course but it's not uncommon. Here's a pic of a net with this kind of input: http://i.stack.imgur.com/3G19K.jpg This is not configured so the input vectors have dimension 0 but each of them can be configured to have any integer dimension.

Comment: OK, I agree. But your question "simulate with 3 concurrent inputs" still remains unclear to me. What do you mean with 3 concurrent inputs? If your input vector has 5 dimensions (3 + 2), concurrent means feed the network with 3 vectors of dimension 5 at the same time? Maybe you can reformulate your question in a more clear way.

Comment: "concurrent inputs" is a matlab term. It means "inputs out of time line"...and it makes sense if you think that in a dynamic network (i.e. recurrent network or with time delays, elman network ecc) the presenting order of inputs affects the output. So a static network can see no difference between "concurrent inputs" and "time series inputs" while a dynamic network returns different outputs